# activities stacking up problem

Tags: android, stack, android-intent

this might be an easy question but i have a notification that when clicked open up the stock messaging app

```
arg1.setClassName("com.android.mms","com.android.mms.ui.ConversationList");
```

but i noticed that every time it is clicked the activity keeps stacking up and i end up having to use the back button a bunch of times to get out of it. I have always used `android:noHistory="true"` in the manifest but obviously i cant do that here so is there a way to do the same thing with when the intent is launched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT. If the activity is already running, it'll be brought to the front.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `arg1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)` before calling your intent, which might solve your problem...